# How to prevent a particular page from showing in the access log on apache

Tags: php, apache

I have shared hosting so I don't have access to apache2.conf but I can do .htaccess files. I'm doing an application in PHP so if there's a PHP solution this is doable for me.

I look up the access logs every now and again just to see who is logging in and what's happenning in general. The problem is that I added a chatrooms feature and the chat update page is constantly being accessed so the whole log fills up with references to just this page. I would like to keep logging every access as it currently stands except I dont want any record of the chat update page to show up on the access log.

Can this be done?

Comment: Check this out: https://serverfault.com/questions/509760/apache-access-log-exclude-static-files-like-cssjspnggif-etc

Comment: @OMiShah `CustomLog` can't be set in .htaccess. Pretty sure that with just .htaccess available for configuration, this won't be possible at all.

Comment: Oh I missed the shared hosting part.

Answer (score 1):

You could include a file with a few lines of code that would log access to a log file to every page you *do* want to have logging. Then use that log file instead of access log altogether. Another solution I would recommend (if the log file doesn't get too huge) is to use some log file reader.

```php
<?php

function getVisitorIP()
{
    $ip = "0.0.0.0";
    try {
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        } else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
            $ip = explode(".", $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']);
            $ip = $ip[3] . "." . $ip[2] . "." . $ip[1] . "." . $ip[0];
        } else if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) || empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
            if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) && empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) && isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
                $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $ip = "unknown";
    }
    return $ip;
}

$my_access_log = __DIR__ . "/data.txt";
$fp = fopen($my_access_log, 'a');
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$ip = getVisitorIP();
$page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$str = "Page $page visited by $ip at $now";
fwrite($fp, $str . "\n");
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: I've already got a kind of alternative log file going for particular events through PHP but Im hoping I can suppress logs to apache for one particular page so that when Im visiting cPanels visitors stuff it still makes sense. Its really the access.log for apache Im trying to prevent being written to in a specific circumstance.